# Não estou conseguindo fazer um teste unitário

Tags: java, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit

Estou com um problema para fazer um método de teste neste programa JAVA.
O método que eu criei foi para verificar se o lobo está morto.

```
@Test
public void verificaSeOLoboMorreAposCompletarAIdade(){
    campo = new Campo(4,4);
    localizacao = new Localizacao(0,0);
    ArrayList<LoboGuara> novosLobos = new ArrayList<>();
    loboGuara = new LoboGuara(false,campo,localizacao);
    for (int i = 0; i >= 7; i++){
        loboGuara.caca(novosLobos);
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(campo.pegarAnimalNaPosicao(0,0) == null);
}
```

Os métodos são privados, juntamente com os respectivos atributos. (Não posso alterá-los)

```
    private static final int IDADE_PROCRIACAO = 10;
    private static final int IDADE_MAXIMA = 150;
    private static final double PROBABILIDADE_PROCRIACAO = 0.75;
    private static final int TAMANHO_MAXIMO_NINHADA = 5;
    private static final int VALOR_FOME_OVELHA = 7;
    private static final Random rand = Randomizador.getRandom();

    private int idade;
    private boolean vivo;
    private Localizacao localizacao;
    private Campo campo;
    private int nivelFome;

    public LoboGuara(boolean idadeRandomica, Campo campo, Localizacao localizacao)
    {
        idade = 0;
        vivo = true;
        this.campo = campo;
        setLocalizacao(localizacao);
        if(idadeRandomica) {
            idade = rand.nextInt(IDADE_MAXIMA);
            nivelFome = rand.nextInt(VALOR_FOME_OVELHA);
        }
        else {
            nivelFome = VALOR_FOME_OVELHA;
        }
    }

    public void caca(List<LoboGuara> novosLobos)
    {
        this.incrementaIdade();
        this.incrementaFome();
        if(vivo) {
            daALuz(novosLobos);
            Localizacao newLocalizacao = procuraComida(localizacao);
            if(newLocalizacao == null) { 
                newLocalizacao = campo.localizacaoAdjacenteLivre(localizacao);
            }
            if(newLocalizacao != null) {
                setLocalizacao(newLocalizacao);
            }
            else {
                setMorte();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean estaVivo()
    {
        return vivo;
    }

    public Localizacao getLocalizacao()
    {
        return localizacao;
    }

    private void setLocalizacao(Localizacao newLocalizacao)
    {
        if(localizacao != null) {
            campo.limpa(localizacao);
        }
        localizacao = newLocalizacao;
        try {
            campo.lugar(this, newLocalizacao);
        } catch (ObjetoInvalidoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void incrementaIdade()
    {
        idade++;
        if(idade >= IDADE_MAXIMA) {
            setMorte();
        }
    }

    private void incrementaFome()
    {
        nivelFome--;
        if(nivelFome == 0) {
            setMorte();
        }
    }

    private Localizacao procuraComida(Localizacao localizacao)
    {
        List<Localizacao> adjacente = campo.localizacoesAdjacentes(localizacao);
        Iterator<Localizacao> it = adjacente.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Localizacao onde = it.next();
            Object animal = campo.pegarAnimalNaPosicao(onde);
            if (animal instanceof Ovelha) {
                Ovelha ovelha = (Ovelha) animal;
                ovelha.setMorte();
                nivelFome = VALOR_FOME_OVELHA;
                return onde;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void daALuz(List<LoboGuara> novosLobos)
    {
        List<Localizacao> livre = campo.localizacoesAdjacentesLivres(localizacao);
        int nascimentos = procria();
        for(int b = 0; b < nascimentos; b++) {
            if (livre.size() > 0) {
                Localizacao loc = livre.remove(0);
                LoboGuara jovem = new LoboGuara(false, campo, loc);
                novosLobos.add(jovem);
            }
        }
    }

    private int procria()
    {
        int nascimentos = 0;
        if(podeProcriar() && rand.nextDouble() < PROBABILIDADE_PROCRIACAO) {
            nascimentos = rand.nextInt(TAMANHO_MAXIMO_NINHADA) + 1;
        }
        return nascimentos;
    }

    private boolean podeProcriar()
    {
        return idade > IDADE_PROCRIACAO;
    }

    private void setMorte()
    {
        vivo = false;
        if(localizacao != null) {
            campo.limpa(localizacao);
            localizacao = null;
            campo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Se alguém puder dar uma luz eu agradeço!

Comment: Poste o código fonte em si em não imagens. Isso facilita para quem for responder.

Comment: Leia isso fazendo favor : https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: As chances de alguém tentar lhe ajudar com os códigos em imagens são muito baixas, assim como o @Zulian citou, poste o código ao invés de imagens

Comment: Agora, sim. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Faltou o `public class LoboGuara` e os imports. A classe `LoboGuara` tem alguns problemas estruturais, mas se você não pode alterar, deixe-se isso quieto. Entretanto, não está claro o que você quer testar exatamente. Você quer testar apenas se o lobo guará morre ou quer testar o comportamento de todos os métodos públicos?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado pela resposta! Estou querendo testar todos o métodos públicos. Quero testar se o loboGuara morre, após atingir o nível de fome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, primeiro que você não postou o seu código completo. Faltou os `import`s, a declaração da classe `LoboGuara` e as classes `Localizacao`, `Campo`, `Animal`, `Ovelha`, `ObjetoInvalidoException` e `Randomizador`. Coloquei a implementação mais simplória possível delas e ficou assim:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class Animal {}

class Campo {

    public Campo(int x, int y) {}

    public void limpa(Localizacao x) {
    }

    public Localizacao localizacaoAdjacenteLivre(Localizacao x) {
        return x;
    }

    public void lugar(LoboGuara x, Localizacao y) throws ObjetoInvalidoException {
    }

    public List<Localizacao> localizacoesAdjacentes(Localizacao x) {
        return Arrays.asList();
    }

    public List<Localizacao> localizacoesAdjacentesLivres(Localizacao x) {
        return Arrays.asList();
    }

    public Animal pegarAnimalNaPosicao(Localizacao x) {
        return null;
    }

    public Animal pegarAnimalNaPosicao(int x, int y) {
        return null;
    }
}

class ObjetoInvalidoException extends Exception {}

class Localizacao {
    public Localizacao(int x, int y) {}
}

class Randomizador {
    public static Random getRandom() {
        return new Random();
    }
}

class Ovelha extends Animal {
    public void setMorte() {}
}

public class LoboGuara extends Animal {
    private static final int IDADE_PROCRIACAO = 10;
    private static final int IDADE_MAXIMA = 150;
    private static final double PROBABILIDADE_PROCRIACAO = 0.75;
    private static final int TAMANHO_MAXIMO_NINHADA = 5;
    private static final int VALOR_FOME_OVELHA = 7;
    private static final Random rand = Randomizador.getRandom();

    private int idade;
    private boolean vivo;
    private Localizacao localizacao;
    private Campo campo;
    private int nivelFome;

    public LoboGuara(boolean idadeRandomica, Campo campo, Localizacao localizacao)
    {
        idade = 0;
        vivo = true;
        this.campo = campo;
        setLocalizacao(localizacao);
        if(idadeRandomica) {
            idade = rand.nextInt(IDADE_MAXIMA);
            nivelFome = rand.nextInt(VALOR_FOME_OVELHA);
        }
        else {
            nivelFome = VALOR_FOME_OVELHA;
        }
    }

    public void caca(List<LoboGuara> novosLobos)
    {
        this.incrementaIdade();
        this.incrementaFome();
        if(vivo) {
            daALuz(novosLobos);
            Localizacao newLocalizacao = procuraComida(localizacao);
            if(newLocalizacao == null) { 
                newLocalizacao = campo.localizacaoAdjacenteLivre(localizacao);
            }
            if(newLocalizacao != null) {
                setLocalizacao(newLocalizacao);
            }
            else {
                setMorte();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean estaVivo()
    {
        return vivo;
    }

    public Localizacao getLocalizacao()
    {
        return localizacao;
    }

    private void setLocalizacao(Localizacao newLocalizacao)
    {
        if(localizacao != null) {
            campo.limpa(localizacao);
        }
        localizacao = newLocalizacao;
        try {
            campo.lugar(this, newLocalizacao);
        } catch (ObjetoInvalidoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void incrementaIdade()
    {
        idade++;
        if(idade >= IDADE_MAXIMA) {
            setMorte();
        }
    }

    private void incrementaFome()
    {
        nivelFome--;
        if(nivelFome == 0) {
            setMorte();
        }
    }

    private Localizacao procuraComida(Localizacao localizacao)
    {
        List<Localizacao> adjacente = campo.localizacoesAdjacentes(localizacao);
        Iterator<Localizacao> it = adjacente.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Localizacao onde = it.next();
            Object animal = campo.pegarAnimalNaPosicao(onde);
            if (animal instanceof Ovelha) {
                Ovelha ovelha = (Ovelha) animal;
                ovelha.setMorte();
                nivelFome = VALOR_FOME_OVELHA;
                return onde;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void daALuz(List<LoboGuara> novosLobos)
    {
        List<Localizacao> livre = campo.localizacoesAdjacentesLivres(localizacao);
        int nascimentos = procria();
        for(int b = 0; b < nascimentos; b++) {
            if (livre.size() > 0) {
                Localizacao loc = livre.remove(0);
                LoboGuara jovem = new LoboGuara(false, campo, loc);
                novosLobos.add(jovem);
            }
        }
    }

    private int procria()
    {
        int nascimentos = 0;
        if(podeProcriar() && rand.nextDouble() < PROBABILIDADE_PROCRIACAO) {
            nascimentos = rand.nextInt(TAMANHO_MAXIMO_NINHADA) + 1;
        }
        return nascimentos;
    }

    private boolean podeProcriar()
    {
        return idade > IDADE_PROCRIACAO;
    }

    private void setMorte()
    {
        vivo = false;
        if(localizacao != null) {
            campo.limpa(localizacao);
            localizacao = null;
            campo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Agora vamos ao teste:

- Primeiro, você usou a condição de parada errada no `for`. Era para ser `x < 7` e não `x >= 7`.
- Segundo, você não verificou se o lobo está vivo!

Com esses ajustes o seu teste deve ficar assim:

```
@Test
public void verificaSeOLoboMorreAposCompletarAIdade() {
    Campo campo = new Campo(4, 4);
    Localizacao localizacao = new Localizacao(0, 0);
    ArrayList<LoboGuara> novosLobos = new ArrayList<>();
    LoboGuara loboGuara = new LoboGuara(false, campo, localizacao);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        loboGuara.caca(novosLobos);
    }
    Assert.assertFalse(loboGuara.estaVivo());
    Assert.assertNull(campo.pegarAnimalNaPosicao(0, 0));
}
```

O teste funciona. Entretanto, uma vez que eu tive que fornecer implementações bem bobas para várias das classes, pode ser que no seu caso não seja assim tão simples. Um outro teste possível do método `isVivo()` seria esse:

```
@Test
public void verificaSeOLoboNaoMorreAntesDeCompletarAIdade() {
    Campo campo = new Campo(4, 4);
    Localizacao localizacao = new Localizacao(0, 0);
    ArrayList<LoboGuara> novosLobos = new ArrayList<>();
    LoboGuara loboGuara = new LoboGuara(false, campo, localizacao);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        loboGuara.caca(novosLobos);
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(loboGuara.estaVivo());
    Assert.assertNotNull(campo.pegarAnimalNaPosicao(0, 0));
}
```

Já um teste para o `getLocalizacao()`:

```
@Test
public void verificaSeOLoboFicaOndeFoiColocado() {
    Campo campo = new Campo(4, 4);
    Localizacao localizacao = new Localizacao(2, 3);
    ArrayList<LoboGuara> novosLobos = new ArrayList<>();
    LoboGuara loboGuara = new LoboGuara(false, campo, localizacao);
    Assert.assertEquals(localizacao, loboGuara.getLocalizao());
}
```

Não é uma boa ideia colocar `Campo` e `Localizacao` como atributos da classe de teste nesse caso porque é o próprio teste que os cria e os usa. Se eles fossem criados no construtor ou em um método anotado com `@Before` ou `@BeforeClass`, aí sim seria o caso. Uma outra alternativa mais avançada seria trabalhar com `@Rule`.